# How to remove scatches from a metal laptop

Tags: laptop

So I was taking my laptop out if my bag and the charger hit the top of the computer and a small scratch that looks kinda like a line of hair is on the laptop and i want to know if there is any way to remove it.

EDIT:

Actually, I was looking into it and I found an article saying that toothpaste with white gel and a microfiber cloth will fix it, do you think that this will work on my model?

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop?

Comment: HP Envy x360 15 inch, the black model

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of metal polishing/buffing compounds around, as well as buffing wheels for bench top grinders, angle grinders, and roto-tools which all can be Googled.

If you have an colored anodized finish, a bit of paint or nail polish might work. Use a fine brush to paint some on, then wipe off anything that overflows the scratch, which can be difficult to impossible to do.

The problem with either of these is: will it match your existing laptops finish? I'm afraid that anything you do will likely make a larger, more noticeable mark than the scratch.

I used to be a computer tech and still work with/on computers (for a total of over 20 years) and scratches are going to continue to happen. No matter how gentle you think you are with your laptop, scratches are going to happen. Most of them will appear more subtly than this one, but they'll happen. I actually recommend against laptops as a professional opinion, since they are more likely to be damaged and destroyed than a desktop.

The best thing (and probably hardest thing) is to accept it, learn to ignore it, and just continue on as if it never happened.

Or, throw a sticker over it. Favorite band, favorite sports team, favorite video game, whatever, as long as you don't mind it.

Comment: Actually, I was looking into it and I found an article saying that toothpaste with white gel and a microfiber cloth will fix it, do you think that this will work on my model?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the depth of the scratch.

A bit of plastic polish should do it, you should only need a small amount. Simply wipe the lid, then put the plastic polish onto a cloth, wipe the lid into a circular motion and then wipe the lid clean.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot really "remove a scratch". At best, you can fill it, or hide it, or repair it.

Why? Because, by definition, a scratch is some material missing, which should not be missing. So you need to either add the missing material, or make it less visible.

The easiest ways to deal with the problem are:

- live with it; it will serve as a reminder to be more careful in the future;
- use a marker (or any other paint) to bring the affected area to the color of the rest of the laptop.

Out-of-the-box idea: using some abrasive something (e.g. sandpaper) cover the laptop with scratches. Instead of (black) it will become metal / shiny. Depending on the skill, it might even look cool. Be careful not to get dirt and metal dust inside the laptop. Nasty things could happen.

---

If you post a picture of the affected area, we might be able to help you more.

---

The trick with the toothpaste usually works with acceptable results with transparent materials. What is does is to round the edges of the scratch to make the scratch less visible. As a result, the damage gets bigger, but less visible. In the case of the laptop, the damage will get bigger, and **more** visible, if I imagine your laptop properly (again, you might want to post a picure).

Comment: Dear brave down-voter, will you please your downvote?